# Initiliazing NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone

If i do this

```
NsMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[array addObject:someObject];

someProperty = array;
[array release];
```

Do i need to add nil to the end of the array, or does the init method do that for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No and NSArrays 's do not end in a nil.

What does need a nil is initilaising an array with a set of objects using arrayWithObjects: or initWithObjects: Here the nil is required to tell at runtime when the list of objects ends as happens with any C variable arguments function e.g. using va_args

Comment: It doesn't tell the compiler, it tells the runtime.

Comment: From http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2005/qa1405.html it is done at runtime